# What would be a good VCS repository to read/help?

Tags: projects, repository

I've been writing code, mostly proprietary, for a long time; spaghetti code and the like. I took a few years out of the industry though and feel like I missed something enormous. I've spent some time studying books but I want to get my hands a little dirty - so I ask, what would be a good VCS repository to read/involve myself with?

Comment: Why repositories? Usually they have the most convoluted code imaginable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) seems to be pretty hot.